# Using .NET class library inside Vue through the Quasar framework

Tags: c#, vue.js, .net-core, electron, quasar-framework

My goal is to create a **Vue js** **Quasar** application (deployed for desktop through **electron**), but I want to use **.NET** and **C#** for the backend. I already have a class library written in C#. Is it possible to fetch data from it in the quasar application?

 
One way that I know to connect **.NET** with frontend frameworks like **Vue** is to make a **web api** in **.NET** and make requests to it using **axios** in **vue**. However this time I want the application to work **offline**. Is there any way to do this?